# Dimensional error while predicting

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network, keras

I have trained a convolutional3d model using [code](https://github.com/lulu920819/keras_dcgan/blob/b8d0b3f7b9364931a1e01c5e78582f26feab534c/example/cnn_3d.py)

Im trying to get the prediction as follows,

```
import cv2
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
import numpy as np

#create an empty frame
frames = []

#defince row, col
img_rows,img_cols,img_depth=16,16,15

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('run.avi')
fps = cap.get(5)

#Use only first 15 frames for prediction
for k in range(15):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame=cv2.resize(frame,(img_rows,img_cols),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    frames.append(gray)


#preprocess
input = np.array(frames)
ipt=np.rollaxis(np.rollaxis(input,2,0),2,0)
reshape_frames = np.expand_dims(ipt, axis=0)

#run prediction
model = load_model('current.h5')
preds = model.predict(reshape_frames)
print(preds)
```

but it fires the following error,

> ValueError: Error when checking : expected conv3d_1_input to have 5
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 16, 16, 15)

How can I be able to sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See in the [docs for convolutional 3D layers](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv3d):

> **Input shape**
>
> 5D tensor with shape: (samples, channels, conv_dim1, conv_dim2, conv_dim3) if data_format='channels_first' or 5D tensor with shape: (samples, conv_dim1, conv_dim2, conv_dim3, channels) if data_format='channels_last'.

So what is bascially happening is that the input shape you provide to your first conv 3D layer does not fit to the expected input.

To solve this you could go as follows:

- change the provided input, so that it matches the expected input (also take into account the `data_format` as noted above). As it looks in your code, you don't use the `img_depth` information at all. You basically provide a 2D image to a 3D conv net.
- Use a 2D convnet and create a new model